# What is the definition of a "first time buyer" with relation to the UK "help to buy isa"?

Tags: mortgage, united-kingdom, isa

I'm very interested in the soon to be released ["help to buy isa"](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-33658144).  I'm unclear on the definition of a first time buyer.

I have owned a house (with my ex wife) but I am no longer on this mortgage, the house is purely in her name now.

My girlfriend has never owned a house.

So two questions:

- Am I a first time buyer?
- Can we still use the isa if we buy a house together (joint mortgage)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to https://www.helptobuy.gov.uk/help-to-buy-isa/faq/#998e24ea-e1f7-648f-8ce9-ff0000ad17aa :

> A first time buyer is someone who does not own, and has never owned, a home anywhere in the UK or the world.

So you don't count.

[The most detailed government guidance I can find](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/413899/Help_to_Buy_ISA_Guidance.pdf) does say (section 3.11) that:

> the government bonus can only be put towards a first home located in the UK with
>   a purchase value of £450,000 or less in London and £250,000 or less in all other
>   parts of the UK
>
> the government bonus can only be used towards a property that is being used for
>   the first time buyer to live in as their only residence and not buy-to-let. This will be
>   enforced by the scheme administrator
>
> ...
>
> accounts are limited to one per person rather than one per home so those buying
>   together can both receive a bonus

Taken together I *think* that means that your girlfriend can get one of these ISAs and use it towards a jointly-purchased house. But you'd be wise to check that with the ISA provider.

Comment: The [helptobuy.gov.uk FAQ](https://www.helptobuy.gov.uk/help-to-buy-isa/faq/) is a good reference for the definition of a first time buyer.